# Constructor Array Allocation Difference between Mac & Linux Machines

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, g++, clang

### Problem

I am currently working through creating a class that has a member variable pointer that will be populated with an array of type T upon construction. My initialization and zeroing of the of the array in the constructor works just fine on my Linux machine but when I run the same code on my M1-series Mac, the array pointers get moved to a *page aligned* memory position.

The compilers I am using are: `g++` on Linux and `clang` on Mac.

### Members & Constructor

```
T* data;
int size;
int count;
int index;

cyclic_array(int size): len{ size }, count{ 0 }, index{ 0 }{
    data = new T[len];    

    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        data[i] = 0;
        printf("%p -> %d\n", &data[i], data[i]);
    }
    
}
```

### Insertion

```
void insert( T&& x ) {
    if( count + 1 > len ){ printf("Need to resize\n"); }
    data[ (index + count) % len ] = x;
    count++;
}
```

### Removal

```
void remove() {
    data[ index ] = 0;
    index = (index%len) + 1;
    count--;
}
```

### Print

```
void print() {
    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
        printf("\n%p -> %d\n", &data[i], data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

### Main

```
int main() {
    cyclic_array<int> ca(4);
    char selection;

    while( selection != 'q' ) {
        printf("Menu Option [ Add ( a ), Remove ( r ), Quit ( any ) ]: ");
        scanf("%s", &selection);
        if( selection == 'a' ){
            int x {0};
            scanf("%d", &x);
            printf("x: %p\n", &x);
            ca.insert( std::move(x) );
            ca.print();
            continue;
        }
        else if( selection == 'r' ){
            ca.remove();
            ca.print();
            continue;
        }
        else
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

### Output

For sanity printing I am just printing the addresses of each index of the array following by `->` and then the de-referenced value at that address, *which should be zero*. I'm aware that I'm accepting a template so I might not want to initialize the value to `0` but I chose `int` as the template type for simplicity.

I also use the same addresses in the output just as a representation.

#### Linux

```
0x5592837e5eb0 -> 0
0x5592837e5eb4 -> 0
0x5592837e5eb8 -> 0
0x5592837e5ebc -> 0

-- Insert Value --

0x5592837e5eb0 -> 69
0x5592837e5eb4 -> 0
0x5592837e5eb8 -> 0
0x5592837e5ebc -> 0
```

#### Mac

```
0x5592837e5040 -> 0
0x5592837e5044 -> 0
0x5592837e5048 -> 0
0x5592837e504c -> 0

-- Insert Value --

0x5592837e5000 -> 69
0x5592837e5004 -> 0
0x5592837e5008 -> 275632
0x5592837e500c -> 1928562
```

For both programs the input from `stdin` is:

```
a
69
q
```

Link to Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/oaW34f9Ex

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The problem may be in the code you don't show. What is `/* resize */`, `/* running */`, `// Process selection`, and `/* insert */`?

Comment: @DanielLangr I omitted that considering the fact that I had a working example. I just added the complete main code.

Comment: I don't see the complete compilable code. What is `/* resize */`. What is `remove`? What is the input (stdin) of your program? You can put the code to some online IDE, such as https://godbolt.org.

Comment: The resize portion was just a print statement and I added the `remove` func

Comment: Note that one problem is already here: `char selection; while( selection != 'q' )`. `selection` is not initialized, it has unspecified value, and reading it results in undefined behavior. Anyway, even in our live demo, the addresses are different before and after insertion: https://godbolt.org/z/P7KzqT1aq.

Comment: Also, this is wrong: `scanf("%s", &selection);`. `%s` is used for reading a string, not a single character. Why do you not use C++ I/O (`std::cin` and `std::cout`)? Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/3hzcsG1q9.

Comment: you're asking us to explain _undefined behaviour_. We can't

Comment: The behaviour is similar to the described one on a Samsung tablet with a Qualcom Snapdragon processor.

Comment: The moving of the array happens exactly when `scanf` is called the first time (add more `ca.print()` to see that). I know that with undefined behaviour anything can happen. But it is still surprising to me that the unrelated array gets moved.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If noone can explain that, we will have to accept that. But still I find the question exciting (although it might have not been asked in a perfect manner) and it would be a pity, if there was not even an idea why the compiler emits code where the array seems to be moved.

Comment: It is not an issue with `scanf` because I have another program that emits the same strange behavior *only* on my M-series macbook and is not using `scanf`. I'm working on getting it into Godbolt for you all.

Comment: @robertstrickland I tried running your program on M1 and changing scanf to take %c resolves the problem. Could you provide that other program that does not use scanf and emits the same strange behavior?